# React app using Context API for theme toggling causes whole app to re-render on change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm building a React app where I'm using the Context API to manage application state, especially for theme changing. Despite having set up my context and provider correctly (to the best of my understanding). I am able to toggle between theme freely however the whole app resets or rerender everytime I toggle
My _app.tsx

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient()

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <ApplicationContextProvider>
                <ChildComponent>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </ChildComponent>
            </ApplicationContextProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    )
}

export interface ChildComponentProps {
    children: ReactNode
}

const ChildComponent = ({ children }: ChildComponentProps) => {
    const { mode } = useApplicationContext()
    const router = useRouter()
    const { userDto, setUserDto } = useApplicationContext()

    const { data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['fetchUserDto'],
        queryFn: () =>
            getAuthenticatedUser().then((res) => {
                if (res === undefined) {
                    console.log('User is not logged in')
                }
                return res
            }),
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setUserDto(data)
        }
    }, [userDto, setUserDto, data])
    const Layout = ({ children }: ChildComponentProps) => {
        if (router.pathname.includes('/my')) {
            return (
                <AuthenticatedLayout userDto={userDto}>
                    {children}
                </AuthenticatedLayout>
            )
        } else {
            return <>{children}</>
        }
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider
            enableSystem={true}
            attribute={'class'}
            forcedTheme={mode}
        >
            <Layout>{children}</Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

and my ApplicationProvider

```
export interface ApplicationContextValue {
    mode: 'dark' | 'light'
    setMode: Dispatch<SetStateAction<'dark' | 'light'>>
 //
}


export const ApplicationContextProvider = ({
    children,
}: ApplicationContextProviderProps) => {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState<'dark' | 'light'>('light')
    // @ts-ignore
    const [userDto, setUserDto] = useState<UserDto>()
    const value: ApplicationContextValue = {
        mode,
        setMode,
        userDto,
        setUserDto,
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Check if running in a browser environment
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const storedMode = window.localStorage.getItem('icovest-theme') as
                | 'dark'
                | 'light'
            if (storedMode) {
                setMode(storedMode)
            }
        }
    }, [])

 
    return (
        <ApplicationContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ApplicationContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Here's a video of my problem.
https://imgur.com/a/1bNmExV

I have tried removing the mode context but the theme won't change.